# Dagger2 dagger.android.* classes does not exist

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm adding Dagger2 to my Android app following the [instructions from the official docs](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html#injecting-activity-objects). I've used Dagger and Dagger2 before, it seems like Google has revamped the implementation for Android as of the following quote;

> The classes in dagger.android offer one approach to simplify this pattern.
>
> ...
>
> Next, make your Application implement HasDispatchingActivityInjector and @Inject a DispatchingAndroidInjector to return from the activityInjector() method:

It looks awesome, but I can't find the package `dagger.android` anywhere, nor do I find anything when I look through the repository, `HasDispatchingActivityInjector` gives no hits on Google at all. Where are these classes described in the docs?

I can find all the other Dagger2 classes alright (Module etc.) so the libs are there.

My dagger dependencies from `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.9'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is listed in the [google/dagger Github repository](https://github.com/google/dagger), under the [`java/dagger/android` subtree](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/java/dagger/android), committed four days ago (Feb 13, 2017 3:58PM PST). This includes [HasDispatchingActivityInjector](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/HasDispatchingActivityInjector.java).

Your gradle file is correct: Dagger's Android extensions are available through an adjacent `dagger-android` package, not through the main `dagger` package. [See Maven's Dagger packages for more details.](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.dagger%22)

EDIT: [As of yesterday the `dagger.android` Android helpers are released in version 2.10-rc1](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.10-rc1)

Comment: Cool it's there! Pretty new stuff I see. Anyway, I have the `com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.9` as seen above, but the latest release was 14 days ago, 11 days before `dagger.android` showed up. It seems to have made the documentation early! I'll mark this as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`dagger.android` classes were added in the **version 2.10** [here are release notes](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.10).

Make your code works you have to update your dagger dependencies from `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.10'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
```